# Adding handler to default http client in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, dotnet-httpclient

Is there a way to add handlers to the default HTTP client in ASP.NET Core?
Something like this?

```
.AddHttpClient()
.AddHttpMessageHandler<Handler1>()
.AddHttpMessageHandler<Handler2>();
```

Comment: You can add an extension method on `IServiceCollection` called `AddHttpClient` that maybe takes a `DelegatingHandler` and then `services.AddSingleton(ctx => new System.Net.Http.HttpClient(handler));`. The issue is you can only add a handler in `HttpClient` constuctor.

Comment: Indeed, remember that using a singleton instead of the IHttpClientFactory is not the recommended way for many applications (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-5.0). But as always, it depends on your use case and your code base.

Answer (score 28):

Documentation states that you can only add handlers or configure the inner most handler to named or typed clients.

Reference [Configure the HttpMessageHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-2.1#configure-the-httpmessagehandler)

> It may be necessary to control the configuration of the inner HttpMessageHandler used by a client.
>
> An `IHttpClientBuilder` is returned when adding named or typed clients. The `ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler` extension method can be used to define a delegate. The delegate is used to create and configure the primary `HttpMessageHandler` used by that client:

```
services.AddTransient<Handler1>();
services.AddTransient<Handler2>();

services.AddHttpClient("configured-inner-handler")
    .AddHttpMessageHandler<Handler1>()
    .AddHttpMessageHandler<Handler2>();
    .ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() =>
    {
        return new HttpClientHandler()
        {
            AllowAutoRedirect = false,
            UseDefaultCredentials = true
        };
    });
```

Answer (score 16):

Upon inspecting the source code of `DefaultHttpClientFactory` (which is both the `IHttpClientFactory` and the `IHttpMessageHandlerFactory` registered by `AddHttpClient` method), it turns out that there is no use registering a custom `IHttpMessageHandlerFactory` because `DefaultHttpClientFactory` never requires it (but directly uses its own method). Of course we could also register a custom `IHttpClientFactory`, but there is a easier way to achieve what we want.

The idea is that `DefaultHttpClientFactory` calls the transient service `HttpMessageHandlerBuilder` during its `IHttpMessageHandlerFactory` implementation, so all we have to do is to register a custom `HttpMessageHandlerBuilder`. For example:

```
public class CustomHttpMessageHandlerBuilder : HttpMessageHandlerBuilder {
    public override string Name { get; set; }
    public override HttpMessageHandler PrimaryHandler { get; set; }
    public override IList<DelegatingHandler> AdditionalHandlers => new List<DelegatingHandler>();
    // Our custom builder doesn't care about any of the above.
    public override HttpMessageHandler Build() {
        return new HttpClientHandler {
            // Our custom settings
        };
    }
}
```

And then register it:

```
services.AddTransient<HttpMessageHandlerBuilder, CustomHttpMessageHandlerBuilder>();
```

And it works.